# user defined function in python to read csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
Reads in a dataset using pandas.

Parameters
----------
file_path : string containing path to a file

Returns
-------
Pandas DataFrame with data read in from the file path
'''
```

I have defined the following UDF but it doesnt work.

def read_data(file_path):
pandas.read_csv('file_path')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the return and the variable shouldn't have quotes

```
import pandas as pd


def read_data(file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame: 
    return pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: i have tried using your code but its showing me FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'file_path' does not exist: b'file_path' when I try to use the file path on the read_data funcion

Comment: What does your file_path variable look like? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: @AbbasKhan you are supposed to run the function with an existing file path. Lets say your file is `/drive/user/my_data_file.csv` then you should run `read_data("/drive/user/my_data_file.csv")`

Comment: thank you very much. actually it was the return. I have used def read_data(file_path): return pd.read_csv(file_path) and it worked